# Using function.toString() with compilers?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, tostring

I'm trying to display to raw code of a few functions as a way to "show my work". It's for financial modelling, and copy+pasting the code is unfeasible, the users often aren't savvy enough to read source code.

function.toString() would be the ideal candidate, but <strike>because I'm using Babel (and will maybe add more in the future)</strike>, the output is scrambled.

Is there a way to get around this?

For example

```
const profit = () => revenue - expenses;

<h1> This is how we calculated profit in the model </h1>
<div>{profit.toString()}</div>
```

but the output is

Update: it turns out that the scrambling below is due to Quokka, not Babel. However, the question still remains. I'd love to know if there's a way to get around this scrambling.

```
function profit(v) { 
    $_$wf(1); 
    return $_$w(1, 28), v.revenue - v.expenses; 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to display the code *and* process your files. If you want to show what you've done, then either don't pre-process your files or have a link to the code, if you wish. The alternative is to pre-process before all other processors and capture the code to the function and attach it to the function object, something like `myFn.showCode()`. But that's ugly and probably error prone.

Comment: Interesting question. Unless there's a specific plugin to do it, I tend to think not. (And that transpilation is very odd, I would have expected simply `var profit = function profit() {
  return revenue - expenses;
};` [like this](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=%3E%201%25%2C%20last%202%20versions%2C%20not%20ie%20%3C%3D%208&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBADgJxAMwJawLwwBQEoYYB8MCApgG6lgCupMAtDKQB5xUSkQDcQA&evaluate=true&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015&version=7.7.5) but you must have other transforms happening...)

Comment: Hah, yeah, it turns out it's from Quokka. My bad!

Comment: If you want to "show your work" then open the project in the IDE of your choice, go to the file and function you want to show and voila, your code the same as you wrote it. If you don't want to show the rest of the file, then copy-paste it into an empty file or wherever and show that off. What'S with this attempt to reverse-engineer your source code from some processed, minified and possibly obfuscated js files?

Comment: It's for financial modelling, the user sometimes needs to see how a number is derived, but might not be literate enough to read the source code. Also, the models are quite complex, so copy+pasting each derived value is unfeasible

Comment: Then *to me* it sounds like you're looking at the problem the wrong way. If a user needs to understand the process, then you need an intermediate representation of the logic performed. This you can then derive into logic the application executes *and* show to the user more readably. It will also allow you to more easily change the process - any user with little technical knowledge would be able to change it to (for example) `profit = (revenue - expenses) * 0.95`. Or whatever - point is, the formula can be changed and the code should still work. You can do that using a rules engine.

Comment: `const fn = eval("() => ...");` ...

Comment: @JonasWilms *ewww*... D: I guess it would work, though but the problem is that if files need processing like Babel(?) then the code might not even work on (all) browsers using this.

Comment: @VLAZ just kidding as always :) sure, a proper way to load the actual sourcecode instad of relying on `.toString` or a formula engine would be the way to go here

Comment: @JonasWilms OK, I did get the joke. My fear was that somebody else might not. Having worked on a *vaguely* similar system (financial one where users had to be able to understand calculations and even change them), we had a somewhat simplified scripting language that went into a file for configuring rules. The system would read the script at runtime and execute it against the data. Users could open the config to see this logic. The result was more readable than a normal programming language but still not exactly for everybody. Still, enough for the business analysts.